# How to get a list of all the subproject recursively within a specific project using Rally webservices?

Tags: rally

I can get a list of all the projects within a workspace using Rally webservices.  But I need to get a list of sub project within a specific project.  How can I accomplish this using Rally webservices?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will simply have to recursively traverse the project hierarchy.  Start with the desired parent project, and then load its Children collection.  Then for each of those projects load their Children collections and so on until you only have leaf projects.

Give it a try and edit your question with some actual code if you get stuck.  If you can say what language/toolkit you're working in it will probably be easier to help as well.